# How can I get less to display \n as a newline?

Tags: text-processing, text-formatting, less, newlines

I have some files containing `\n` newlines that I am viewing with `less`.  I would like to be able to have less display those newlines as actual newlines.

For example an array:

```
Array\n(\n    [Color] => Blue\n    [Size] => M\n    [ID] => 123\n    [Questions] => 0\n    [AnotherRandomElement] => 0\n)\n
```

If the newlines were actually shown as newlines:

```
Array
(
    [Color] => Blue
    [Size] => M
    [ID] => 123
    [Questions] => 0
    [AnotherRandomElement] => 0
)
```

Obviously much more readable.

I can do this by replacing the chars and pipe into less with something like `awk  '{gsub("\\\\n","\n")};1' < myfile.txt | less`, but it seems like there has to be a way to get `less` to just do it by itself...

Comment: `less` does not interpret `\n` as newline (or `\t` as tab for that matter). You will have to preprocess your file.

Comment: shouldn't newlines show up as ... new lines? Are those "newlines" actually the two characters \ and n ?

Comment: @JeffSchaller, Yeah, they apparently aren't "normal" newlines.  I'm just getting this string from a `print_r($array)` in PHP.

Comment: @Kusalananda, if that's true, do you want to post it as an answer?

Comment: Probably not, since there might be a better way of outputting your data from PHP which gets rid of the issue completely, but I don't know that language.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as I know, `less` doesn't have the option to perform substitution.

As you suggest, the best option is almost certainly going to involve pre-processing then pipe to `less`. It can still be written fairly elegantly, using `sed`:

```
sed <filename> -e 's|\\n|\n|g' | less
```

Answer (score 2):

This feels risky:

```
printf "$(< myfile.txt)" | less
```

Comment: This is great. It also handles `\t`